# Requirement for applying a Schengen Visa if I'm on my husband's visa in Dubai

Tags: schengen, paperwork, dubai

I'm on my husband's visa in Dubai, and my husband and I are planning to get a Schengen Visa... Are there any additional requirements if I'm under my husband's visa? Though I'm on my husband's visa, I'm also working as well. I've got all the requirements already, like a letter from my employer, bank statement, hotel bookings, and flight as well. I just want to make sure that I will be providing all the documents required.

Comment: Citizenship might play a role...

Answer (score 3):

There are no specific requirements for you. I had a similar situation with a colleague who was going on a trip with his wife, they look at the following:

1. Travel reservation
2. Hotel reservation
3. Itinerary (in his case, he was traveling to multiple member states)
4. Proof of sufficient funds (bank statement)
5. Validity of residency and travel documents (the residency should be valid for 6 months, and so should your passport).
6. Insurance valid for the travel period.

In addition, as he was an expat, the following additional documents:

7. Letter of employment, stating length of employment, position.
8. Salary certificate (if salary is not indicated in the letter of employment).

Note that you have to make two separate appointments, even if you are traveling together on the same itinerary; in other words two people cannot apply if there is a single appointment.

I am not sure if this is valid for all member states but it was the case for the Netherlands.

Answer (score 1):

You want to apply for a Schengen visa in Dubai and your immigration status in Dubai is spouse dependent. Assuming that your spouse is non-EEA, and you have no relatives in the EEA...

There are no additional requirements other than providing assurance that you can return to Dubai (Question 18 on the form).  Because your husband is the primary, you'll need to include his visa and work contract (or whatever is equivalent).

For questions 35 and 36: Assuming you have joint accounts where you have full access to the account, your bank statements will be sufficient.

Being employed in Dubai gives an additional incentive for you to avoid overstaying, but it's not related to being a dependent.

The rest of the application should be filled out as normal.